# Custom Filter Syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working through a [tutorial](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/EnA7rkqH82/angularjs-filters) on creating filters in angular.  I am confused with some of the implementation and it comes to down fundamental javascript. Here is the cod snippet:

```
// on the app object, the method filter is called passing a name parameter and the function
myApp.filter('reverse', function () {
  return function (text) {
// now a function that accepts text as a parameter is returned    
return text.split("").reverse().join("");
// the text parameter splits, revers, and joins the text parameter.
  }
});
```

My question is why can't something like this be written instead? What's the purpose of returning the function in the first snippet on line two?

```
myApp.filter('reverse', function (text) {
    return text.split("").reverse().join("");
});
```

Comment: Because the function you pass to `filter` is dependency injectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you pass to `filter` is dependency injectable. Imagine you inject a few things:

```
myApp.filter('uc', function($http, myService, text) {
  return text.toUpperCase();
});

myApp.filter('repeat', function($http, $location, myService2, text) {
  return text + text;
});
```

How do you know where `text` is in the list of arguments? Now those filters don't compose because the arguments don't match. If you return a function that always takes the value as first argument, then everything composes nicely, and you can do:

```
repeat(uc(value))
```